# Calcular la matriz inversa

Tags: python

tengo un problema para obtener la matriz inversa.
Tengo el programa para obtener la matriz adjunta y el determinante pero no puedo obtener la matriz inversa (cada entrada de la matriz adjunta se debe dividir entre el determinante) y la matriz de la que se obtendrá su inversa debe ser generada con números aleatorios, espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
from numpy import matrix,zeros,size
from numpy.linalg import det

A=matrix([[-2,-6,2],[0,1,3],[0,0,6]])
MC=matrix(zeros((3,3))) # Matriz de cofactores
idx=matrix(range(3))
for i in range(size(A,0)):
    for j in range(size(A,1)):
        fix=idx[idx!=i]
        cox=idx[idx!=j]
        cof=A[[[fix[0,0]],[fix[0,1]]],cox]
        MC[i,j]=pow(-1,i+j)*det(cof)

MACJ=MC.transpose() # Matriz adjunta 
print ("Matriz de cofactores\n",MC)
print ("Matriz adjunta\n",MACJ)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
def det(l):
    n=len(l)
    if (n>2):
        i=1
        t=0
        sum=0
        while t<=n-1:
            d={}
            t1=1
            while t1<=n-1:
                m=0
                d[t1]=[]
                while m<=n-1:
                    if (m==t):
                        u=0
                    else:
                        d[t1].append(l[t1][m])
                    m+=1
                t1+=1
            l1=[d[x] for x in d]
            sum=sum+i*(l[0][t])*(det(l1))
            i=i*(-1)
            t+=1
        return sum
    else:
        return (l[0][0]*l[1][1]-l[0][1]*l[1][0])
print(det([[48,53,31,2,45],[21,24,38,23,45],[72,25,26,23,34],[48,53,31,21,45],[32,56,21,24,38]]))
```

Comment: Si estás usando `numpy`, ¿por alguna razón estas resolviendo la determinante con código base?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta. Se me solicito no usar funciones para calcular el determinante e inversa de manera directa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `numpy.linalg`, que además del determinante `det`, también te calcula la matriz inversa `inv`:

```
from numpy import matrix, zeros, size
from numpy.linalg import det, inv

matriz = matrix([[-2, -6, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 0, 6]])
matrizInv = inv(matriz)
print(matrizInv)
```

Devuelve:

```
[[-0.5        -3.          1.66666667]
 [ 0.          1.         -0.5       ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.16666667]]
```